# Show Total member in different way

Tags: php

i m working Multi-level marketing concept, after calculation store all member in this $member variable, i want to show all members in diffrent way

**Condition:** First 4 box not greater than 10 and last 4 box not greater than 100

**Case 1:** $member = 37, show member like that

[image]

**Case 2:** $member = 300 , show member like that

[image]

```
$a = array_fill(1, $member, 1);
$chunked_array = array_chunk($a, 10);

foreach($chunked_array as $key=>$single_arr)
    { ?>
      <div class="id_box1"><?php echo array_sum($single_arr); ?></div>
  <?php } ?>
```

my above code is working fine if i have 40 member or less , but i dont know how to handle code if member is greater than 40

help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First list what you need:

- There is 4 boxes that cannot be bigger than 10.
- There is another 4 boxes that cannot be bigger than 100.
- All boxes have to be filled in order.

Then create a logic that accomplishes that:

- Fill first 4 boxes with 10 and minus it from member variable. If $member lower than 10, just write it to current box.
- Fill otger 4 boxes with 100 and minus it from member variable. If $member lower than 10, just write it to current box.

As you see, this two operation is nearly same. Then you can make it one operation:

- Fill 8 boxes [if first 4 boxes = 10, else 100] and minus it from $member. If $member lower than [if first 4 boxes = 10, else 100] just write it to current box.

Here is a few solution (there could be more):

Php 5.3+ Solution with 2 array using Closure:

```
<?php
$member = 300;

$small_boxes = array_map(function ($value) use(&$member) {
    $return = $member > 10 ? 10 : $member;
    $member = $member > 10 ? $member - 10 : 0;

    return $return;
}, array_fill(0, 4, 0));

$big_boxes = array_map(function ($value) use(&$member) {
    $return = $member > 100 ? 100 : $member;
    $member = $member > 100 ? $member - 100 : 0;

    return $return;
}, array_fill(0, 4, 0));

var_dump($small_boxes, $big_boxes);
?>
```

Php 5.3+ solution with 1 array using Closure:

```
<?php
$member = 300;
$count = 1;
$boxes = array_map(function ($value) use(&$member, &$count) {
    if ($count <= 4)
    {
        $return = $member > 10 ? 10 : $member;
        $member = $member > 10 ? $member - 10 : 0;
    }
    else
    {
        $return = $member > 100 ? 100 : $member;
        $member = $member > 100 ? $member - 100 : 0;
    }

    $count++;

    return $return;
}, array_fill(0, 8, 0));

var_dump($boxes);
?>
```

Php 5.3- solution with 2 array using foreach:

```
<?php
$member = 300;

$small_boxes = $big_boxes = array_fill(0, 4, 0);

foreach ($small_boxes as $key => $value)
{
    if ($member > 10)
    {
        $small_boxes[$key] = 10;
        $member -= 10;
    }
    else
    {
        $small_boxes[$key] = $member;
        $member = 0;
        break;
    }
}

foreach ($big_boxes as $key => $value)
{
    if ($member > 100)
    {
        $big_boxes[$key] = 100;
        $member -= 10;
    }
    else
    {
        $big_boxes[$key] = $member;
        $member = 0;
        break;
    }
}

var_dump($small_boxes, $big_boxes);
?>
```

Php 5.3- solution with 1 array using foreach:

```
<?php

$member = 300;

$box = array_fill(0, 8, 0);

foreach ($box as $key => $value)
{
    if ($key < 4)
    {
        $box[$key] = $member > 10 ? 10 : $member;
        $member = $member > 10 ? $member - 10 : 0;
    }
    else
    {
        $box[$key] = $member > 100 ? 100 : $member;
        $member = $member > 100 ? $member - 100 : 0;
    }
}

var_dump($box);

?>
```

Use whatever you like :)

You just need to print it/them using foreach.

Comment: Just curious. Which solution did you choose?

Comment: i used this one Php 5.3- solution with 1 array using foreach:

Answer (score 2):

If $member variable is a simple number, then making an array of ($member) elements just for the sake of dividing it into 8 slices is... a bit redundant. I'd personally go with 2 "for" loops, it's sort of crude, but is obvious and should work fine:

```
$calcval=$member
$a=array();
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
    {
    $a[$i]=( ($calcval>10) ? 10 : $calcval);
    $calcval -= $a[$i];
    }
for($i=4;$i<7;$i++)
    {
    $a[$i]=( ($calcval>100) ? 100 : $calcval);
    $calcval -= $a[$i];
    }
```

Or, if you want to stick with arrays, add something like this to your code before output:

```
$sliced_array=array_slice($a, 40);
$chunked_array2 = array_chunk($sliced_array, 100);
$output = array_merge(array_slice($chunked_array, 0, 4),array_slice($chunked_array2, 0, 4));
```

Had no chance to test solutions above, but I think you can get the general idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
 $member = 370;
 if ($member <= 40) {
$count = 40;
$a = array_fill(1, $count, 1);
$chunked_array = array_chunk($a, 10);
foreach($chunked_array as $key=>$single_arr){  
  ?><div class="id_box1"><?php echo array_sum($single_arr); ?></div>
<? } 
} else if ($member > 40) {
$count = 40;
$b = array_fill(1, $count, 1);
$chunked_array = array_chunk($b, 10);
foreach($chunked_array as $key=>$single_arr){ 
?>
<div class="id_box1"><?php echo array_sum($single_arr); ?></div>
<?
}
$c = array_fill(1, ($member - $count), 1);
$chunk_array = array_chunk($c, 100);
foreach($chunk_array as $key=>$single_array){
    ?>
<div class="id_box2"><?php echo array_sum($single_array); ?></div>
    <?
}
}  
?>
```

Comment: try this it worked and also you can change the count variable accordingly

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = array_fill(0, $member, 1);
if ($member > 40) {
    $decs = array_slice($a, 0, 40);
    $chunked_array = array_chunk($decs, 10);
} else {
    $chunked_array = array_chunk($a, 10);
}
// draw 10 box
foreach($chunked_array as $key=>$single_arr)
{ ?>
      <div class="id_box1"><?php echo array_sum($single_arr); ?></div>
<?php } 

// draw 100 box
if ($member > 40) {
    $hundred = array_slice($a, 40);
    $chunked_array = array_chunk($hundred, 100);
    foreach($chunked_array as $key=>$single_arr)
    { ?>
      <div class="id_box1"><?php echo array_sum($single_arr); ?></div>
    <?php } 
}
?>
```